# "Error: could not find a part of the path" during Azure web app deployment

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-1.0

I want to deploy an ASP.NET Core web app to Azure.

In my solution folder, I have 2 projects, both references `Newtonsoft.Json` library.

As I attempt to deploy through local Git repo, it shows an error at "Running deployment script", which results in the following activity log.

The error messages of the log hints that it tries to look for a bin folder within Newtonsoft.Json which doesn't exist. Any idea how to fix this and what is wrong?

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling ASP.NET 5 Web Application deployment.
'dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1' is already installed in D:\local\UserProfile\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1.
Adding D:\local\UserProfile\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin to process PATH
Microsoft .NET Development Utility Clr-x86-1.0.0-rc1-16231

  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\src\NyxProjectGenerator\project.json
Writing lock file D:\home\site\repository\src\NyxProjectGenerator\project.lock.json
Restore complete, 2895ms elapsed
Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\wrap\Newtonsoft.Json\project.json
Writing lock file D:\home\site\repository\wrap\Newtonsoft.Json\project.lock.json
Restore complete, 18ms elapsed
Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\wrap\Xamasoft.JsonClassGenerator\project.json
Writing lock file D:\home\site\repository\wrap\Xamasoft.JsonClassGenerator\project.lock.json
Restore complete, 22ms elapsed
Total time 3330ms

Feeds used:
    https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/
Microsoft .NET Development Utility Clr-x86-1.0.0-rc1-16231

Copying to output path D:\local\Temp\8d34698522cd8f8

...
Using Package dependency System.Runtime.Extensions 4.0.0
    Source D:\local\UserProfile\.dnx\packages\System.Runtime.Extensions\4.0.0
Error: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\home\site\repository\wrap\Newtonsoft.Json\bin\Debug\net451'.
    Target D:\local\Temp\8d34698522cd8f8\approot\packages\System.Runtime.Extensions\4.0.0

...
Using Project dependency Newtonsoft.Json 1.0.0 for .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1
  Packing nupkg from Project dependency Newtonsoft.Json
    Source D:\home\site\repository\wrap\Newtonsoft.Json\project.json
    Target D:\local\Temp\8d34698522cd8f8\approot\packages\Newtonsoft.Json\1.0.0

Building Newtonsoft.Json for .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1
  Using Project dependency Newtonsoft.Json 1.0.0
    Source: D:\home\site\repository\wrap\Newtonsoft.Json\project.json

  Using Assembly dependency fx/mscorlib 4.0.0
    Source: D:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\mscorlib.dll

  Using Assembly dependency fx/System 4.0.0
    Source: D:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.dll

  Using Assembly dependency fx/System.Core 4.0.0
    Source: D:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.Core.dll

  Using Assembly dependency fx/Microsoft.CSharp 4.0.0
    Source: D:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\Microsoft.CSharp.dll

An error has occurred during web site deployment.
Error: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\home\site\repository\wrap\Newtonsoft.Json\bin\Debug\net451'.\r\nc:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\52.50302.2113\bin\scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
```

Comment: How do you reference Newtonsoft.Json from your projects? Are your projects  both .xproj-based with corresponding project.json files?

Comment: Please post the contents of your `project.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

This error message, which includes the "wrap" folder, suggests to me that you have added a ref to the Newtonsoft Assembly directly.

> Error: Could not find a part of the path       'D:\home\site\repository\wrap\Newtonsoft.Json\bin\Debug\net451'

Instead you should reference Newtonsoft via a NuGet package ref in your project.json file

```
"dependencies": {
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "8.0.2"
},
```